# selecting nodes based on the attribute value

Tags: xml, xslt-1.0, xslt-grouping, muenchian-grouping

I have been struggling for days to determine how to take an XML file of game results (teams and final scores) and generate a team standings list shows each team along with how many times they won, lost or tied based on game status(played). I was able to display team standings on both game status(played and pending). I want to display team standings that are played  only.Any help would be greatly appreciated.

here is my xml code:

```
<Schedule>
    <game status="played">
      <Home_Team>A</Home_Team>
      <Away_Team>B</Away_Team>
      <Date>2013-06-15</Date>
      <Home_Team_Score>3</Home_Team_Score>
      <Away_Team_Score>3</Away_Team_Score>
   </game>

   <game status="played">
      <Home_Team>A</Home_Team>
      <Away_Team>C</Away_Team>
      <Date>2013-06-17</Date>
      <Home_Team_Score>7</Home_Team_Score>
      <Away_Team_Score>4</Away_Team_Score>
   </game>

   <game status="played">
      <Home_Team>C</Home_Team>
      <Away_Team>A</Away_Team>
      <Date>2013-06-19</Date>
      <Home_Team_Score>3</Home_Team_Score>
      <Away_Team_Score>3</Away_Team_Score>
   </game>

   <game status="played">
      <Home_Team>D</Home_Team>
      <Away_Team>C</Away_Team>
      <Date>2013-06-19</Date>
      <Home_Team_Score>8</Home_Team_Score>
      <Away_Team_Score>7</Away_Team_Score>
   </game>

   <game status="pending">
      <Home_Team>B</Home_Team>
      <Away_Team>C</Away_Team>
      <Date>2013-07-25</Date>
      <Home_Team_Score>0</Home_Team_Score>
      <Away_Team_Score>0</Away_Team_Score>
   </game>

   <game status="pending">
      <Home_Team>C</Home_Team>
      <Away_Team>D</Away_Team>
      <Date>2013-07-27</Date>
      <Home_Team_Score>0</Home_Team_Score>
      <Away_Team_Score>0</Away_Team_Score>
   </game>
</Schedule>
```

Here is my xsl code:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
    <xsl:key name="TeamByName" match="Home_Team|Away_Team" use="."/>
      <xsl:template match="/*">
       <html>
          <body>
     <table border="1">
      <tr>
       <td>Team</td>
       <td>Wins</td>
       <td>Losses</td>
       <td>Tie</td>
      </tr>
      <xsl:for-each select="//game[@status='played']">
      <xsl:apply-templates select="(*/Home_Team | */Away_Team)[generate- id()=generate-  id(key('TeamByName', .)[1])]">
    <xsl:sort select="."/>
<     /xsl:apply-templates>
      </table>
      </body>
      </html>
     </xsl:template> 

      <xsl:template match="Home_Team|Away_Team">
      <tr>
       <td>
        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
       </td>
       <td>

        <xsl:value-of select=
        "count(key('TeamByName', .)
                     [self::Home_Team
                    and
                      ../Home_Team_Score > ../Away_Team_Score 
                    or
                      self::Away_Team
                    and
                      ../Away_Team_Score > ../Home_Team_Score
                     ]
                 )"/>

       </td>
       <td>

        <xsl:value-of select= "count(key('TeamByName', .)
                     [self::Home_Team
                    and
                      ../Away_Team_Score > ../Home_Team_Score
                    or
                      self::Away_Team
                    and
                      ../Home_Team_Score > ../Away_Team_Score
                     ]
                 )"/>

       </td>
       <td>

        <xsl:value-of select="count(key('TeamByName', .)
                     [../Home_Team_Score = ../Away_Team_Score]
                 )"/>

       </td>
      </tr>
     </xsl:template>
    </xsl:stylesheet>
```

Output should like in the form of:

```
<table border="1">
   <tr>
      <td>Team</td>
      <td>Wins</td>
      <td>Losses</td>
      <td>Ties</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>A</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>2</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>B</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>1</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>C</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>1</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>D</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>0</td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: What is your output ? Can't immediately see any problem. Your select="//game[@status='played']" ought to work

Comment: what is your actual output - and what is the actual problem?

Comment: @peter The output should be in a table that has team names and their standings wins, losses and ties.When <xsl:for-each select="//game[@status='played']"> is applied I'm not getting out whereas when the condition is not applied I'm getting output for both status(played and pending).I want just the game stadings that are played only.